installing Samba on 24.04
My system:
Linux machinename 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 21:40:26 UTC` 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I try to install Samba on this system, I get the following error:
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.12t64 : Depends: libpython3.12-stdlib (= 3.12.3-1ubuntu0.2) but 3.12.6-1+jammy1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

That last bit indicates held broken packages exist, but sudo apt -f install shows nothing wrong, apt-mark showhold displays nothing.

Any idea where 3.12.6-1+jammy1 is from?

None.  apt policy libpython3.12 responds with

  Installed: (none)  

  Candidate: (none)  

  Version table:```
  
Now that you mention it, I'm on noble, not jammy...but it's not showing as a held package, so I'm baffled.  Turns out there's a LOT i can't install since python3 is the system python.

You may want to check that with apt-cache policy libpython3.12*. There must be some repository, PPA enabled. Jammy uses python3.10 by default, not 3.12.

Thanks for your reply @mikewhatever.  I'm on noble, not jammy so 3.12 is appropriate, and output from apt-cache policy libpython3.12* does not list any PPAs, only us.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com
Any other thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.
